# Entity Framework didn't apply migrations using Database.SetInitializer()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a simple ASP.NET Web Pages site using Entity Framework 6.1 (the Web Pages live in the standard project with csproj so that I could use EF Code First with migrations). This is in my _AppStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
}
```

It all compiles fine, I have confirmed that the code indeed go through this line but the migrations aren't applied - I have confirmed that by manually executing `Update-Database` which did the work correctly.

What could be wrong? Do I need to set something else for it to work?

Comment: I have same piece of code like you and everything works fine. Maybe try to disable automigrations in Configuration class.

Comment: Automatic migrations are disabled. mr100 pointed out the real reason behind this in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling SetInitializer (as name says) does not create database or apply migrations. It just sets the initializer. It will be invoked for instance when you would like to save data to db with SaveChanges method and the database won't exist at that time. To force immediate migration you should use DbMigrator class:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new MyMigrationsConfiguration());
migrator.Update();
```

Comment: Good point! My assumption was based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer where they state that it will "automatically upgrade the database (by applying any pending migrations) when the application launches". So that is incorrect, thanks for your explanation.